# filtering result by sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table name is `ads` like that:

```
    id    ad_country          ad_gender     ad_birthday
     1     UK                  Male          2012-02-26
     2     sangapor            Female        2011-05-29
     3     UK                  Female        2010-04-12
```

and i have two drop down select options

```
   one  is to select country
```

and

```
    one is to select year
```

is it possible to make one sql query which affine the results to get :

how many male in every country selected and by the year selected also.
how many female in every country and by the year selected also
thx

i have tried this sql but didnt work.

```
    SELECT COUNT(ad_gender) AS male FROM ads  WHERE '".$_POST['country']."' = ad_country  AND ad_gender = Male AND '".$_POST['year']."' = '".$row2['ye']."'
```

note that
$row2['ye'] is from $sql2 as follows

```
     SELECT ad_birthday,(substr(ad_birthday , 1, 4)) AS ye FROM ads
```

EDITED my post as its not much code i gave , here my new question
                    [my new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394474/filtering-results-by-two-select-options)

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried.

Comment: how would your expected output look like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simpliest way to do this with using `group by` and `having` is by using `case` in your query.

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ad_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalMale,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ad_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalFemale
FROM    ads
WHERE   ad_country = 'countryHere' AND
        YEAR(DATE(ad_birthday)) = yearHere
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e11b3/1)

One more thing, never ever pass the value from user directly to your sql statement as it may be vulnerable with **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

     $query = "    SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN ad_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalMale,
                           SUM(CASE WHEN ad_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalFemale
                   FROM     ads
                   WHERE    ad_country = ? AND
                            YEAR(DATE(ad_birthday)) = ?"

    $country = 'UK';
    $year = 2012;
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $country);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $year);
    if ($stmt->execute()) 
    {
         while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
         {
              print_r($row);
         }
    }

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: you explained good and it was mybe me who didnt give whole code so i give it. Edited my post , thx .

Comment: **Always** [disable emulated prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/508666) when using the MySQL driver with PDO!!

Comment: @PeeHaa thank you for this, I didn't know this until now. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be a pretty simple query to execute, so I'm wondering why it isn't working for you. What have you tried so far?

```
select
  ad_country as country,
  YEAR(ad_birthday) as year,
  ad_gender as gender,
  count(id) as count
from ads
where ad_country in ('/* your country params here*/')
group by ad_country, year, ad_gender
having YEAR(ad_birthday) in ('/* your year params here*/')
```

You shouldn't need to have a second SQL query just to pull the date part out of the table - use the [built-in SQL date & time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for this.

Also, this is going off-topic but the code you have posted looks like inline SQL. Please use [parameterized queries](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) instead or you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ad_country, count(case when ad_gender = 'male' then 1 end) male, 
count(case when ad_gender = 'female' then 1 end) female, year(ad_birthday) year
from ads
group by ad_country, year(ad_birthday)
```

Comment: you explained good and it was mybe me who didnt give whole code so i give it. Edited my post , thx .