# filtering results by two select options

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table name is `ads` like that:

```
    id    ad_country          ad_gender     ad_birthday
     1     05                       01              2012-02-26
     2     15                       02              2011-05-29
     3     78                       02              2010-04-12
```

and table `field_values` like that :

```
 fieldid    fieldtitle  fieldvalue
   14         Male         01                // ads.ad_gender =  field_values.fieldvalue
   14         Female       02                //ads.ad_country =  field_values.fieldvalue
   13         Afghanistan  03 
   13         Albania      04
   13           Algeria    05
  ...             ...                ...
```

**and the code :**

```
        session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['country'])){

         $country = $_POST['country']; 
        $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
            }
    if (isset($_POST['year'])){
       $year = $_POST['year']; 
       $_SESSION['year'] = $_POST['year'];
       }
```

and i have two drop down select options

**one  is to select option of countries:**

```
 <form action="" id="countryform" method="post">
   <select id="country" name ="country" size="1" class="select" onchange="this.form.submit();;" >
       <option value="0" >Please Select a Country</option>

              <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM field_values WHERE fieldid = 13 GROUP BY fieldtitle ");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){  
            ?>

       <option value="<?php echo $row['fieldtitle'] ;?>" <?php

           if ($country == $row['fieldtitle']) { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> > <?php echo $row['fieldtitle'] ;?>
      </option>
             <?php } ?>
   </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="<?php echo $country;  ?>" />
 </form>
```

**and one is to select option of year :**

```
<form action="" id="yearform" method="post">
  <select id="year" name ="year" size="1" class="select" onchange="this.form.submit();;" >
       <option value="0" >Please Select the Year</option>

<?php 
 $sql6 = mysql_query("SELECT  ad_birthday,(substr(ad_birthday , 1, 4)) AS year FROM ads GROUP BY year ") ;
while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($sql6) ){
   ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $row6['year'] ;?>" <?php

    if ($year == $row6['year']) { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> > <?php echo $row6['year'] ;?>
  </option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenselect" value="<?php echo $year;  ?>" />
</form>
```

**the echo part is as follows :**

```
         $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ad_gender) AS male FROM ads INNER JOIN  field_values ON  field_values.fieldvalue = ads.ad_country WHERE '".$_POST['country']."' = field_values.fieldtitle AND ad_gender = 01  ");
           $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2) ; 
        $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ad_gender) AS female FROM ads INNER JOIN  field_values ON  field_values.fieldvalue = ads.ad_country WHERE '".$_POST['country']."' = field_values.fieldtitle AND ad_gender = 02  ");
           $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3) ; 

          echo "There are ".$row2['male']." male <br />";
          echo "There are ".$row3['female']." female<br />";
```

but i couldnt come around it , i think something is missing in if isset statment.

**what i want is :**

if i select country and year it will echo how many male and female in this country and by this year.
thx for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.gender, COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM ads a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS country FROM field_values) b 
        ON b.fieldvalue = a.ad_country
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS gender FROM field_values) c
        ON c.fieldvalue = a.ad_gender
GROUP BY c.gender
```

You can add the following filters before `GROUP BY`:

- Year: `WHERE YEAR(a.ad_birthday) = '2012'`
- Country: `WHERE b.country = 'Albania'`

See it [in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ad66/1).

Then after you convert your `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_` or `PDO` (because it is being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com)), you can simply display the result by gender:

```
| GENDER | COUNT |
------------------
| Female |     2 |
|   Male |     1 |
```

**Update 1**

To implement this code, you can try something like this (not tested):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user_name", "password", "stock");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT c.gender, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ads a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS country FROM field_values) b ON b.fieldvalue = a.ad_country
INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS gender FROM field_values) c ON c.fieldvalue = a.ad_gender
WHERE b.country = ? AND (YEAR(a.ad_birthday) = ? OR YEAR(a.ad_birthday) <> NULL) GROUP BY c.gender");

mysqli_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $country, $year) or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "There are " . $row[count] . ' ' . $row[gender] . "<br />\n";
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

**Update 2**

Since you are unable to use `mysqli` for some reason, the code below should work. Please note that it assumes that country is not empty.

```
$query = "SELECT c.gender, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ads a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS country FROM field_values) b ON b.fieldvalue = a.ad_country
    INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS gender FROM field_values) c ON c.fieldvalue = a.ad_gender
    WHERE b.country = " . mysql_real_escape_string($country);

if(isset($year)) $query .= " AND YEAR(a.ad_birthday) = " . mysql_real_escape_string($year);

$query .= ' GROUP BY c.gender';

$sql2 = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    echo "There are " . $row[count] . ' ' . $row[gender] . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: which sql i will replace by yours in my sql ? as u see i have 4 sqls :)

Comment: u didnt understand what i want maybe :( , i have two select options and by them i filter how many male and female in this country and that year selected .  u didnt use my html select options , because i select by them .

Comment: i have make your update code but without `$link` connect because it connected .but didnt work i make like that :`$stmt = mysqli_prepare("SELECT c.gender, .... your code");
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $country, $year) ;
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "your_echo";
}`

Comment: @goodmood `ss` is a type specifier for the corresponding bind variables. `s` = string, `i` = integer, etc. You can [read here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more info.

Comment: ok thx and what about my changing which i posted up , i removed the connect link but something is wrong

Comment: @goodmood `$link` needs to be `mysqli`. Are you receiving any other errors?

Comment: no error but just didnt echo anything when removed link , and when used yours without removing link didnt want connect to host , i used all right parameters , but my host didnt want to connect directly thats why i want remove this connect link

Comment: i will remove my `if (isset($_POST['country'])){..` , because u made `if(isset($year))` and this `$year` u have use it from my isset , so thats why i asked if i remove my isset . thx for ur time

Comment: ok , this is how i done and the whole code , i dont know whats wrong , i have done like what u said . http://pastie.org/4710715

Comment: it echo but its wrong echoing , and its same echoing in all countries .every country same result and its wrong .maybe because u made `WHERE 1` in ur sql , i dont know :).

Comment: @goodmood Right before `mysql_query`, can you add `echo $query;` and report back with the result?

Comment: `SELECT c.gender, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ads a INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS country FROM field_values) b ON b.fieldvalue = a.ad_country INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS gender FROM field_values) c ON c.fieldvalue = a.ad_gender WHERE 1 AND YEAR(a.ad_birthday) = 2011 GROUP BY c.gender`

Comment: `SELECT c.gender, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ads a INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS country FROM field_values) b ON b.fieldvalue = a.ad_country INNER JOIN (SELECT fieldvalue, fieldtitle AS gender FROM field_values) c ON c.fieldvalue = a.ad_gender WHERE 1 AND b.country = Albania GROUP BY c.gender`

Comment: it seems they are separated country and year , if i select country the sql is only country and if i select year the sql is only year , so how it will filtrate by together country and year

Comment: :) , u were right :) it was the last try ;) , thx so much , it works very good :) ,

Comment: how it will be this last file which u gave me if we use PDO , because i want leave this mysql_* , i think its better to use PDO , can you give link of your last code which worked by PDO ? thx.